# How to tell Skype on Mac that it is ok to open even though downloaded from Internet?

Tags: mac, security, macbook, skype

After rebooting my Macbook Pro, when I click Skype to open it, it says "This file has been downloaded from the Internet, are you sure you want to open it?"

[image]

It doesn't give me the option "this session" and "forever" as other applications did.

**How can I tell Skype that it is ALWAYS ok to execute on my Macbook?**

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing the dialog with "this session" and "forever". If you select *Open* once, it removed the attribute and you're done for the future (until you download a new version of the application).

Comment: @Daniel Beck, I think it is likely to be related to whether the application has been properly signed...

Comment: Are you running Skype from the disk image (dmg) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

choice 1. disable all this sort of prompt

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO
```

choice 2. disable this sort of prompt for 1 application

```
xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine /Path/to/application/
```